# Android : How to click on a disabled button to enable it

Tags: java, android, robotium

I am using Robotium for android UI automation. I am stuck at a point
where i am trying to click on a button in the application that is
initially disabled. Robotium fails to find the text or button. I am
trying the following code.

```
 if (solo.searchText(".*android.*"))
{
  solo.clickOnText(".*android.*");
}

else solo.goBack();
```

Clicking on the button will enable it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you cannot click on a disabled button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
 for(View v: solo.getViews()) {
 if(v instanceof Button) {
    if( ((Button)v).getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("some text") )
{
            solo.clickOnView(v);
            solo.sleep(3000);
            break;
    }
 }

}
```